# How to fix: 'torch.dll not found' error in Visual Studio after successful CMake build

Tags: libtorch

I am trying to set up a simple example of C++ code using the libtorch library. I built the project sucessfully as described on the Pytorch tutorial website. Now I defined the example-app build folder as starting point and try to run it in debugging mode. I get an error message that the torch.dll could not be found but it is listed in the external dependencies folder.

I reinstalled the libtorch library. no success,
I ran VS as administrator. no success,
I rebuilt the project. no success,
I set libtorch to the environment variables. no soccess

```
C++ Code: 

#include <torch/torch.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  torch::Tensor tensor = torch::rand({2, 3});
  std::cout << tensor << std::endl;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0 FATAL_ERROR)
project(example-app)
find_package(Torch REQUIRED)

add_executable(example-app app.cpp)
target_link_libraries(example-app "${TORCH_LIBRARIES}")
set_property(TARGET example-app PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 11)
```

My error message tells me (I translated it to english):

> The Execution of the code cannot be continued, because torch.dll could
>   have not been found. Reinstalling the programm might resolve this
>   problem

Comment: you need to deploy the dll next to you executable.
I suggest using a custom command that execute post build and copy the dll to the $<TARGET_DIR:example-app>

Comment: Thank you, it worked well but I have some question according to this. Why do we use CMake at this point, whe it does not the work? Why does it not work to set the lib path in the VC++ directories at the porperties in addition to the CMake procedure? This would help me a lot to understand all this things.

Comment: ah, hum there is two kind of library static and dynamic, Torch seems to be compiled in the dynamic mode meaning that it will be loaded at run time rather than compile time.
that's why if the executable try to load the dll, but couldn't find it it couldn't start.
The library path you just set match the impl library that has been generated along with the dlls it contains symbols exported by the dlls. this link is made at compile time.
but its just symbols, not implementation of the pytorch lib.
Take a look about the differences between static libraries, and dll (on windows)

Answer (score 1):

You have to copy the depending *dll next to your executable or must add the libtorch/bin to your Path.

```
if (MSVC)
    file(GLOB TORCH_DLLS "${TORCH_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/*.dll")
    add_custom_command(TARGET example-app
                 POST_BUILD
                 COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different
                 ${TORCH_DLLS}
                 $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:example-app>)
endif (MSVC)
```

This is my solution for your case

Answer (score 0):

Adding *libtorch/lib* to PATH worked for me